# Simplest way of outputting debug content into file

Tags: php, logging

I've got an applicaiton with various php scripts. I want to get an idea of how much time it takes for the execution to move from one point to another (there are many such points).

I was looking for a simple php line that I can insert without modification, at different spots in my code and get an output file (NOT generated html) which shows something like:

```
FILENAME      FUNCTION        LINENUMBER      TIMESTAMP
```

I've started using this:

```
file_put_contents('/home/default/public_html/debug.log',  __FILE__ . "\t" .
 __FUNCTION__ . "\t" . __LINE__ . "\t" . microtime(true)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

which is good, but are there better ways of doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple way to do this, you can either use the global PHP error system with `trigger_error()` and a `E_NOTICE` level, or the `error_log()` function to log in a separate file.

I your case I would recommend the second solution.

---

With the `trigger_error()`:

```
<?php
    trigger_error("Call will start now", E_NOTICE);
    startTheHugeCall();
    trigger_error("Call is finished", E_NOTICE);
?>
```

With the `error_log()` :

```
<?php
    error_log("Call will start now", 3, "/var/tmp/debugfile.log");
    startTheHugeCall();
    error_log("Call is finished", 3, "/var/tmp/debugfile.log");
?>
```

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - trigger_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php)
- [php.net - Error handling, Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)
- [php.net - error_log()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [XDebug extension](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to generate raw profiling data.  It will generate files in your /tmp directory by default that you can crunch using command line tools or various GUIs.